# Input not working after jquery slideToggle();

Tags: jquery, html, input, slidetoggle

I have the Following code:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Code" name="Subj_code" id="Subj_code" style="width:100%;">
```

An input box that I will animate using this jquery:

```
$("input[type=text]").slideToggle(200);
```

why is it that when I toggle(hide) and toggle again(unhide) I can no longer enter anything to it?

but if I Enter something before doing the same thing, the text will disappear but will reappear when I enter something to it.

Comment: How exactly are you bringing focus to a hidden element?

Comment: What browser are you testing. It works in FF mac... http://jsfiddle.net/cYfeA/

Comment: Try wrapping the input in a div and applying the animation to the container div

Comment: @vyx.ca beat me to it. Needs to be wrapped in a div.

Comment: @Daedalus I'm really sorry, I get the ambiguity of my question. I've edited it to be more clearer. anyways thanks.

Comment: @vyx.ca I'll try your suggestion. :)
because it's a good Idea, I didn't think of doing that. Thanks I'll comment the results.

Comment: @vyx.ca Your comment was the answer. Wrapping it with a div with overflow: hidden; was the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the element with a `div`
and add `overflow: hidden;` to the wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Code" name="Subj_code" id="Subj_code" style="width:100%;">
</div>
```

JS

```
$("div").slideToggle(200);
```